# Updating OpenSSL 3.0.10 in Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: updates, openssl, vulnerability

How to update `openssl` in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The current version is `openssl` 3.0.2. But it have vulnerability. So I need to update to `openssl` 3.0.10. It's still not available in Ubuntu repository.

The following are the vulnerability with `openssl` 3.0.2: CVE-2023-2975, CVE-2023-3446 and CVE-2023-3817

Comment: What CVE/vulnerability are you worried about?   As security fixes are backported to the current packages by default you need to look up what vulnerability you're worried about & start from there using https://ubuntu.com/security/cves or other site.

Comment: Iam worried about the following CVE.CVE-2023-2975,CVE-2023-3446,CVE-2023-3817

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do anything you'll regret later. Let's go through these CVEs and see what they're about:

> #### CVE-2023-3817 & CVE-2023-3446
>
> Published: 31/19 July 2023
>
> Issue summary: Checking excessively long DH keys or parameters may be
> very slow. 
> ... 
> *An application that calls DH_check() and supplies a key or parameters obtained from an untrusted source could be vulnerable to a Denial of Service attack.*
>
> #### CVE-2023-2975
>
> Published: 14 July 2023
>
> Issue summary: The AES-SIV cipher implementation contains a bug that
> causes it to ignore empty associated data entries which are
> unauthenticated as a consequence.
> ... 
> *As this issue does not affect non-empty associated data authentication and we expect it to be rare for an application to use empty associated data entries this is qualified as Low severity issue.*

The first 2 (CVE-2023-3817 & CVE-2023-3446) causes a long response time under certain conditions (which could theoretically lead to a DoS situation), and the last one (CVE-2023-2975) causes unauthenticated *empty* data.

All those CVEs are rated as *low* severity, meaning they'll get a patch when the Ubuntu Security Team believes this can fit into the releases schedule.

If you think you can make a better judgment of the CVEs than the Ubuntu Security Team, you are of course welcome to compile a newer version of the library yourself, but in this case you'll also have to maintain this for yourself going forward.

Most users are better off trusting the Ubuntu Security Team in these matters.